# How to reload a specific tag in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to reload the UserPlaylist tag after running the onChangeTracks() function in order to update it's contents but I'm not sure how to re-execute a specific tag if possible.

Parent Component:

```
render(){
    return(
      <li><UserPlaylist onChange={this.onChangeTracks}/></li>
    );
}
```

UserPlaylist Component (Child Component):

```
render() {
    return(
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { 
            this.getPlaylists() //Have tracks load immediately
        }),
        <select value={"DEFAULT"} onChange={this.props.onChange}> 
            <option value="DEFAULT"> Add to Playlist </option>
            <option value="new"> New Playlist </option>
            {
                this.state.users_playlists.map((playlist, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={playlist.id}> { playlist.name }</option>
                ))
            }
        </select>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components will rerender every time their state is updated. So you should update the state of your `Parent` component whenever the `this.onChangeTracks` function is invoked. Since `this.state.currentTrack` is being passed in as a prop to `UserPlaylist`, once it is updated via a call to `setState` the `UserPlaylist` component will receive new props and should rerender those new props accordingly.

Example:

```
onChangeTracks(val) {
  ...
  this.setState({currentTrack: val});
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-poincare-xku89?file=/src/UserPlaylist.js) that updates the "New Playlist" `select` element whenever the `onChange` event is called.

Here's how it works: First, the `useEffect` hook fires and loads in data from the `examplePlaylists` variable. In your app, you should populate this with the data you have saved in your database or `localStorage`, etc. This data is passed to the `playlists` state which uses the `useState` hook. Whenever a person selects an option from the dropdown menu, the `onChange` event is fired and calls the `handleUpdatePlaylists` function. This function first prompts the user to enter the name of their new playlist. It then updates the `playlists` state through the `updatePlaylists`function. Now, since the state has changed, the component will rerender and map over all the playlists, displaying their names in the dropdown menu. All without needing to refresh the page.

Of course, since I don't have a DB to save these to, the new playlists will disappear on page refresh. But you can write logic to save them however you wish.

And while this works, I think that you should look to using buttons and the `onClick` event instead of a `select` element to handle this logic. Since a new playlist is created whenever an option is selected, then clicking on the name of any playlist will also create them. This doesn't appear to be intended functionality.

So to summarize: handle updates to your components by changing their state. Once state changes, the components will rerender with their new state available for you to work with.

Comment: That makes sense, however what if I remove track={currentTrack}. I realized my actual code doesn't have a use for passing that down. I edited the questions code to make it more clear

Comment: The issue I'm having is when a user clicks a 'New Playlist' in the select tag, the new playlist won't show up as an 'option' tag in the UserPlaylist component unless I reload the page manually. However I want it to be done without having to manually reload the page.

Comment: @surpol I see. Would you mind posting the rest of your code on Codesandbox and sending me the link? I could take a better look at it there

Comment: I mentioned the reason just 1 minute prior to ur message. I made an edit to the previous message

Comment: @surpol Sorry, didn't see your other message. I edited my message after I saw it. Post the link to your Codesandbox and I'll see if I can get it working for you

Comment: It's just too much code since I'm using spotify's api to put into codesandbox, I also did try to do a dummy setState in the Playlist component function onChangeTracks and pass it into UserPlaylist, but it still didn't re-render

Comment: @surpol I understand, I'll try and work with the code in the problem tomorrow and see what I can do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216461/discussion-between-itsanewabstract-and-surpol).

Comment: its ok i figured it out, I just made an onClick="this.getPlaylist" for the select tag in userPlaylist, now it rerenders everytime i add a new playlist. Thanks for the help though